# STL smart pointers vs Qt smart pointers?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, stl

I see that Qt has their own templates of smart pointers. My question is, how to choose between two? Are there cases when Qt smart pointers perform better than STL or vice versa?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but Qt licensing would probably be a good thing to take into consideration.

Comment: You'll find the performance difference (if any) by measuring. Please, feel free to go ahead.

Comment: There is no QTL but Qt, I fixed the post. And the question is so not new. Just search.

Comment: I doubt there are significant performance differences; most likely the Qt implementations are there primarily because Qt predates a lot of STL functionality.  Use whichever version you prefer (keeping in mind that using Qt implementation means your code will only compile as part of a Qt program, which might limit its usefulness e.g. as a general-purpose library)